# SharePoint REST API result not containing lookup field

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

I have a simple rest call on a lookup field:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Planning')/items(1)/?$select=Surveyor
```

however this returns 400, i know the field is definitely in the Planning list and it is a site column,

I do however, see SurveyorId, but i cant expand this.

Sorry for little information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this field require expansion? if so make sure to try:

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Planning')/items(1)/?$select=Surveyor/Title&$expand=Surveyor/Title